# Define methods from template at runtime in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Say I have the following classes:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end

class Bar
    def initialize(name)
        @foo = Foo.new
        @foo.name = name
    end
end
```

I'd like to define an accessor on Bar that is simply an alias to foo.name. Easy enough:

```
def name
  @foo.name
end

def name=(value)
  @foo.name = value
end
```

With only one property, this is easy enough. However, say Foo exposes several properties that I want to expose through Bar. Rather than defining each method manually, I want to do something like this, though I know the syntax isn't right:

```
[:name, :age].each do |method|
  def method
    @foo.method
  end

  def method=(value)
    @foo.method = value
  end
end
```

So...what is the correct way of defining methods like this?

Comment: Btw, your example code won't actually work because `foo` is a local variable and goes out of scope at the end of the `initialize` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[:name, :age].each do |method|
  define_method(method) do
    foo.send(method)
  end

  define_method("#{method}=") do |value|
    foo.send("#{method}=", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sweet, just what I was looking for. Out of curiousity, is there a performance issue with using foo.send? I was hoping to define the body of the method as a string replacing "method" with the action name.

Comment: Yes, `Object#send` is slower.  Whether this matters or not depends entirely on how often you dispatch methods in this way.  To define a method body as a `String` you'll need to use one of the `eval` methods, which is slower still.  It also may come with a number of security implications.

Answer (score 2):

To define a method dynamically you can use `define_method` which takes the method name as a symbol or string argument.

To call a method dynamically you can use `send` which also takes the method name as a symbol or string.

```
[:name, :age].each do |method|
  define_method(method) do
    @foo.send(method)
  end

  define_method("#{method}=") do |value|
    @foo.send("#{method}=", value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Bah, you beat me to it.  I love how our code is almost identical.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

See the [`Delegator` class](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html) in the Ruby Standard Library, depending on how many methods you want to pass along.